# Tell OpenAPI TypeScript Fetch API client to include credentials for all requests

Tags: openapi, fetch-api, openapi-generator

I use [openapi-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) to generate a TypeScript Fetch API client. This API client communicates with an API server via CORS. However, [the Fetch API does not include credentials in CORS requests by default.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials) So although I can authenticate with the API server, any subsequent reqests from the API client do not include the authenticated credentials.

Is there a way for me to specify that the generated TypeScript Fetch API client should include credentials for all requests?

Comment: _Seems_ like you should be able to [customize the TS template](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/templating/) to generate `fetch`es with the right [credentials argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). But that doc makes even the simplest codegen customization look pretty complex, either because it is that way, or because the doc is badly written. Personally, I'd avoid that approach, and just pass all my API requests through a custom TS class that sets the `credentials` argument properly.

Comment: @Noah would you have ideas of how to go about this?

Comment: Maybe with an `HttpInterceptor`, if you are using Angular. Otherwise, to give you better advice, I think we'd have to know what the generated code looks like, and how your app is using it.